# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in C:\xampp\htdocs\FB_com.php on line 15

Tags: php

Anyone know how to solve this problem.

```
<?php

//ADD XFBML

add_filter('language_attributes', 'fbcomments_schema');

function fbcomments_schema($attr) {

$options = get_option('fbcomments');

if (!isset($options)) {$options = "";}

if (!isset($options)) {$options = "";}

if ($options == 'on') {$attr .= "n xmlns:og=","http://ogp.me/ns#";}

if ($options == 'on') {$attr .= "n xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"";}

return $attr;

}

//ADD OPEN GRAPH META

function fbgraphinfo() {

$options = get_option('fbcomments'); ?>

<meta property="fb:app_id" content="<?php echo $options; ?>"/>

<meta property="fb:admins" content="<?php echo $options; ?>"/>

<?php

}

add_action('wp_head', 'fbgraphinfo');

function fbmlsetup() {

$options = get_option('fbcomments');

if (!isset($options)) {$options = "";}

if ($options == 'on') {

?>

<!-- Facebook Comments for WordPress: http://3doordigital.com/wordpress/plugins/facebook-comments/ -->

<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>(function(d, s, id) {

var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

if (d.getElementById(id)) return;

js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;

js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/<?php echo $options; ?>/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=<?php echo $options; ?>";

fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<?php }}

add_action('wp_footer', 'fbmlsetup', 100);

//COMMENT BOX

function fbcommentbox($content) {

$options = get_option('fbcomments');

if (!isset($options)) {$options = "off";}

if (!isset($options)) {$options = "off";}

if (!isset($options)) {$options = "off";}

if (!isset($options)) {$options = "off";}

if (!isset($options)) {$options = "off";}

if (!isset($options)) {$options = "off";}

if (

(is_single() && $options == 'on') ||

(is_page() && $options == 'on') ||

((is_home() || is_front_page()) && $options == 'on')) {

if ($options == 'on') {

if ($options == '') {

$commentcount = "<p>";

} else {

$commentcount = "<p class="".$options."">";

}

$commentcount .= "<fb:comments-count href=".get_permalink()."></fb:comments-count> ".$options."</p>";

}

if ($options != '') {

if ($options == '') {

$commenttitle = "<h3>";

} else {

$commenttitle = "<h3 class="".$options."">";

}

$commenttitle .= $options."</h3>";

}

$content .= "<!-- Facebook Comments for WordPress: http://3doordigital.com/wordpress/plugins/facebook-comments/ -->".$commenttitle.$commentcount;

if ($options == 'on') {

$content .= "<div class="fb-comments" data-href="".get_permalink()."" data-num-posts="".$options."" data-width="".$options."" data-colorscheme="".$options.""></div>";

} else {

$content .= "<fb:comments href="".get_permalink()."" num_posts="".$options."" width="".$options."" colorscheme="".$options.""></fb:comments>";

}

if ($options != 'no') {

if ($options != 'off') {

if (empty($fbcomments[linklove])) {

$content .= '<p>Powered by Facebook Comments</p>';

}}}

}

return $content;

}

add_filter ('the_content', 'fbcommentbox', 100);

function fbcommentshortcode($fbatts) {

extract(shortcode_atts(array(

"fbcomments" => get_option('fbcomments'),

"url" => get_permalink(),

), $fbatts));

if (!empty($fbatts)) {

foreach ($fbatts as $key => $option)

$fbcomments[$key] = $option;

}

if ($fbcomments[count] == 'on') {

if ($fbcomments[countstyle] == '') {

$commentcount = "<p>";

} else {

$commentcount = "<p class="".$fbcomments[countstyle]."">";

}

$commentcount .= "<fb:comments-count href=".$url."></fb:comments-count> ".$fbcomments[countmsg]."</p>";

}

if ($fbcomments[title] != '') {

if ($fbcomments[titleclass] == '') {

$commenttitle = "<h3>";

} else {

$commenttitle = "<h3 class="".$fbcomments[titleclass]."">";

}

$commenttitle .= $fbcomments[title]."</h3>";

}

$fbcommentbox = "<!-- Facebook Comments for WordPress: http://3doordigital.com/wordpress/plugins/facebook-comments/ -->".$commenttitle.$commentcount;

if ($fbcomments[html5] == 'on') {

$fbcommentbox .=    "<div class="fb-comments" data-href="".$url."" data-num-posts="".$fbcomments[num]."" data-width="".$fbcomments[width]."" data-colorscheme="".$fbcomments[scheme].""></div>";

} else {

$fbcommentbox .= "<fb:comments href="".$url."" num_posts="".$fbcomments[num]."" width="".$fbcomments[width]."" colorscheme="".$fbcomments[scheme].""></fb:comments>";

}

if (!empty($fbcomments[linklove])) {

$fbcommentbox .= '<p>Powered by Facebook Comments</p>';

}

return $fbcommentbox;

}

add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');

add_shortcode('fbcomments', 'fbcommentshortcode');

?>
```

Comment: SO is not a debugging service believe it or not... please just include the *relevant* code. Though I'm guessing your issue is here: `{$attr .= "n xmlns:og=","http://ogp.me/ns#";}` ... but the next line is wonky too.

Comment: The syntax coloring above clearly shows a string quotes error ...

Answer (score 1):

Your string uses quotes, but has quotes inside the string! You need to use single quotes if this is the case.

Change

```
if ($options == 'on') {$attr .= "n xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"";}
```

to

```
if ($options == 'on') {$attr .= 'n xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"';}
```

Another way is to escape the quotes with a backslash:

```
if ($options == 'on') {$attr .= "n xmlns:fb=\"http://ogp.me/ns/fb#\"";}
```